# Как исправить ошибку Undefined variable при написании бота?

Tags: python, бот

Ошибка `"lb" is not defined Pylance(reportUndefinedVariable)`

Пишу голосового ассистента, запускаю, а после произнесения фразы выдает выше описанную ошибку, пробовал обьявить глобально, не помогло. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно исправить.

```
def talk():
    global text, clear_task
    text = ''
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Я вас слушаю: ')
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=3)
        try:
            text = (r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")).lower()
        except(sr.UnknownValueError):
            pass
        except(TypeError):
            pass
        os.system('cls')
        lb['text'] = text
        clear_task()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Насколько я знаю это из за строки lb['text'] = text, а сказанный текст который говорит человек хранится в audio

Comment: Ответ очевиден. Определить эту переменную. Откуда она у вас вообще взялась? Она есть за пределами показанной функции?